# ASP.NET MVC 3 form submit affects RenderAction handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have control for user authorization which includes form, two textboxes and submit button.
This control included in the master page through RenderAction method.
I have registration page (its view included through RenderBody method) also with form. When I submit data from the registration form, the login control is triggered also and its handler (controller method for handling POST data) is called. Below you can see controller methods for authorization.
How can I prevent sending POST data to the login control after submitting data from other forms?

```
        [HttpPost]
        public RedirectResult LogIn(AuthViewModel authResult)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                userService.LogInUser(authResult.Login, authResult.Password, Request.UserHostAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["AuthMessage"] = GetValidationMessage();
            }
            string redirectUrl = "/";
            if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            {
                redirectUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
            }
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);

        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult LogIn()
        {
            if (userService.IsUserLoggedIn())
            {
                User currentUser = userService.GetLoggedInUser();
                ViewBag.LoggedInMessage = currentUser.FullName + "(" + currentUser.Login + ")";
            }
            return PartialView("AuthControl");
        }

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <div>
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("SearchControl");}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right_menu">
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderAction("LogIn", "Navigation");}
            </div>
                @{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Navigation");}
            <div>
                 @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Messages");}
            </div>
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderAction("TagCloud", "Navigation");}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main_content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

AuthControl:

```
@model AuthViewModel

<div class="rounded-corners auth-panel">
    @if (ViewBag.LoggedInMessage == null)
    {
        <div class="auth-container">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Navigation"))
            {
                <div>
                    <label for="Login">
                        Login:
                    </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new { @class="middle-field"})
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Password">
                        Password:
                    </label>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class="middle-field"})
                </div>
                <div class="in-center">
                    <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/submit.png")"/>
                </div>
            }
        </div>

        <div class="error-msg">
            @if (TempData["AuthMessage"] != null)
            { 
                @Html.Raw(TempData["AuthMessage"].ToString())
            }
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
         </div>
        <div class="small-nav-message">
            <a href="#" class="registration-link">Registration</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Registration page:

```
RegistrationViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
}
@if (TempData["RegistrationFinished"] == null || !(bool)TempData["RegistrationFinished"])
{
<div class="post content-holder">
    <div class="fields-holder">
        <div >
            <div class="error-msg">
                @if (TempData["ValidationMessage"] != null)
                { 
                    @Html.Raw(TempData["ValidationMessage"].ToString())
                }
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {   
                <span>
                    Email:
                </span>
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.Email)
                </span>
                <span>
                    Password:
                </span>
                <span>
                     @Html.PasswordFor(v => v.Password)
                </span>
                <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
            }
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
else
{
    <div>
        Activation link was sent to your email.
    </div>
}
```

Comment: [as noted here](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html) "Note you are not allowed to nest FORM elements!"

Comment: In my case forms are not nested.

Comment: Could you please post the markup?

Comment: What does the Registration page look like?

Comment: @SteveMallory, this is simple form, I published it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I check IsChildAction property from the controller context. Also I have to clear the model state.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(AuthViewModel authResult)
        {
            if (!this.ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    userService.LogInUser(authResult.Login, authResult.Password, Request.UserHostAddress);
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["AuthMessage"] = GetValidationMessage();
                }
                string redirectUrl = "/";
                if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                {
                    redirectUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                }
                return Redirect(redirectUrl);
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            return PartialView("AuthControl");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Registration view, change

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Registration"))
```

In a single controller, single Action scenario, the extra specific routing information is not required, but obviously the routing engine can't figure out on it's own which controller/action to route to with multiple controllers/actions.

**Edit** based on comments:

So this is a routing problem. Try adding a specific route for your Registration action. Something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Register", // Route name
    "{controller}/Index/{registrationResult}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "{controller}", 
        action = "Selector", 
        registrationResult= UrlParameter.Optional
        }
);
```

'registrationResult' would be the name of the parameter in the post Action. I'm thinking that the view models are so similar the routing engine can't differentiate between the two. Add the above route *before* the default route and it should match it when the registration form is submitted.

Comment: I added additional information, but unfortunately I get the same result.

Comment: @eternity can you load up the form and verify the action attributes of both forms? The other thing I would like to see is your RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax

Comment: There is only default route {controller}/{action}/{id}. Registration form looks like <form action="/registration" method="post">

Comment: And LogIn form looks like <form action="/Navigation/LogIn" method="post">

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately it still does not work. However, I found question about a similar problem in Phil Haack's blog http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx. He advises do not put form in the partial view (in comments).